# How to calculate jump based on delta time?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, physics

I'm trying to make a little game with JavaScript (no engine) and I want to get rid of frame-based animation.

I successfully added delta time for horizontal movements (work fine with 60 or 144fps).

But I can't make it work with the jump, height (or the strength) isn't always the same, and I don't know why.

I already tried (And still had the exact same problem):

- Passing Delta Time at the end of `update()`: `x += Math.round(dx * dt)`
- Changing `Date.now()` to `performance.now()`
- Not rounding `DeltaY`
- Locking Jump Height

I made a simplified example with 2 jump type, height locked jump and a normal jump (IDK what to call it). Both have the same problem.

```js
const canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2'),
      ctx2    = canvas2.getContext('2d');



// CLASS PLAYER ------------------------

class Actor {
  constructor(color, ctx, j) {
    this.c     = ctx
  
    this.w     = 20
    this.h     = 40
    this.x     = canvas.width /2 - this.w/2
    this.y     = canvas.height/2 - this.h/2
    this.color = color

    // Delta
    this.dy = 0

    // Movement
    this.gravity   =  25/1000
    this.maxSpeed  = 600/1000
    
    // Jump Height lock
    this.jumpType = (j) ? 'capedJump' : 'normalJump'
    this.jumpHeight = -50

    // Booleans
    this.isOnFloor = false
  }
  
  
 // Normal jump
 normalJump(max) {
   if(!this.isOnFloor) return
   
   this.dy        = -max
   this.isOnFloor = false
 }
 
  
 // Jump lock (locked max height)
 capedJump(max) {
     const jh = this.jumpHeight;
     if(jh >= 0) return
     
     this.dy += -max/15
     if(jh - this.dy >= 0) {
       this.dy = (jh - this.dy) + jh
       this.jumpHeight = 0
     } else {
       this.jumpHeight += -this.dy
     }
 }
 
 
 
 update(dt) {
   const max     = this.maxSpeed*dt,
         gravity = this.gravity*dt;
   
   // JUMP
   this[this.jumpType](max)
  
   // GRAVITY
   this.dy += gravity
   
   
  // TOP AND DOWN COLLISION (CANVAS BORDERS)
  const y = this.y + this.dy,
        h = y      + this.h;
  
  if (y <= 0) this.y = this.dy = 0
  else if (h >= canvas.height) {
    this.y          = canvas.height - this.h
    this.dy         = 0
    this.isOnFloor  = true
    this.jumpHeight = -50
  }
  
  // Update Y
  this.y += Math.round(this.dy)
 }
 
 
 draw() {
 const ctx = this.c
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
 }
}
const Player  = new Actor('brown', ctx,  false)
const Player2 = new Actor('blue',  ctx2, true)



// ANIMATE -----------------------------

let lastRender = 0
let currRender = Date.now()
function animate() {
  // Set Delta Time
  lastRender = currRender
  currRender = Date.now()
  let dt     = currRender - lastRender
  
  // CANVAS #1 (LEFT)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  background(ctx)
  
  Player.update(dt)
  Player.draw()
  
  
  // CANVAS #2 (RIGHT)
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height)
  background(ctx2)
  
  Player2.update(dt)
  Player2.draw()
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()



// EVENT LISTENERS -----------------------

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (Player.keys.hasOwnProperty(e.code)) Player.keys[e.code] = true
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (Player.keys.hasOwnProperty(e.code)) Player.keys[e.code] = false
})


// Just a function to draw Background nothing to see here
function background(c) {
 const lineNumber = Math.floor(canvas.height/10)
  
  c.fillStyle = 'gray'
 for(let i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++) {
   c.fillRect(0, lineNumber*i, canvas.width, 1)
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<canvas width="100" height="160" id="canvas"></canvas>
<span>Normal</span>
</div>

<div>
<canvas width="100" height="160" id="canvas2"></canvas>
<span>Locked</span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29617/how-to-make-a-character-jump
Your getting weird results because your math is wrong in a nutshell.

Comment: I'm sorry, I maybe miss something but I didn't see any difference between my code an the code on the post you just send.

Comment: You should take a look at this book https://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/programming-game-ai-by-example-mat-buckland/1100116543/2661414254304?st=PLA&sid=BNB_ADL+Marketplace+Good+Used+Textbooks+-+Desktop+Low&sourceId=PLAGoNA&dpid=tdtve346c&2sid=Google_c&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpsLkBRDpARIsAKoYI8yCdZwPgFm0V3_Ud3h9aH9MW9i3060U6pCC5jHcUiRHz1iMQsomHRcaAqzTEALw_wcB only $3, use to be 50+. It's what we used in college. It's good but the example code is all c++. The code is simple enough and doesn't really matter. What matter is the explanation of the math. You should be really using vectors.

Comment: Lastly, don't build your own game engine. It seems like you are fairly new to programming. Building games is HARD. Building a game engine make that seem easy. Use Phase or something like it.

Comment: Thanks for the book, I will take a look !
I don't want to use Game Engine, I want to learn and see how far I can get (I don't make my game for real gaming purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would refactor the code:

- Don't use `dy` for both speed and position (which you seem to be doing). Rename it `vy` and use it purely as the vertical velocity.
- Move `isOnFloor` to a function so that we can always check for collisions with the floor.
- Decouple the jump functions from actual movement updates. Just make them set the vertical velocity if the player is on the floor.
- Perform top / bottom collision checking separately depending on the direction of movement.
- Don't round `DeltaY` - it'll mess up small movements.

With these changes in place, the movement behavior is correct and stable:

```js
const canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1'),
      ctx1    = canvas1.getContext('2d'),
      canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2'),
      ctx2    = canvas2.getContext('2d');

// Global physics variables
const GRAVITY   = 0.0015;
const MAXSPEED  = 0.6;
const MAXHEIGHT = 95;


// CLASS PLAYER ------------------------

class Actor {
  constructor(C, W, H, J) {
    // World size
    this.worldW = W;
    this.worldH = H;

    // Size & color
    this.w = 20;
    this.h = 40;
    this.color = C;

    // Speed
    this.vy = 0;

    // Position
    this.x = W/2 - this.w/2;
    this.y = H/2 - this.h/2;

    // Jump Height lock
    this.jumpCapped = J;
    this.jumpHeight = 0;
  }

  // move isOnFloor() to a function
  isOnFloor() {
    return this.y >= this.worldH - this.h;
  }

  // Normal jump
  normalJump() {
    if(!this.isOnFloor()) return;

    this.vy = -MAXSPEED;
  }

  // Jump lock (locked max height)
  cappedJump(max) {
    if(!this.isOnFloor()) return;

    this.vy = -MAXSPEED;
    this.jumpHeight = max;
  }

  update(dt) {
    // JUMP
    if (this.jumpCapped)
      this.cappedJump(MAXHEIGHT);
    else
      this.normalJump();

    // GRAVITY
    this.vy += GRAVITY * dt;
    this.y += this.vy * dt;
   
    // Bottom collision
    if (this.vy > 0) {
      if (this.isOnFloor()) {
        this.y = this.worldH  - this.h;
        this.vy = 0;
      }
    }
    else 
    // Top collision
    if (this.vy < 0) {
      const maxh = (this.jumpCapped) ? (this.worldH - this.jumpHeight) : 0;
      if (this.y < maxh) {
        this.y = maxh;
        this.vy = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

const Player1 = new Actor('brown', canvas1.width, canvas1.height, false);
const Player2 = new Actor('blue',  canvas2.width, canvas2.height, true);


// ANIMATE -----------------------------

let lastUpdate = 0;
let randomDT = 0;
function animate() {
  // Compute delta time
  let currUpdate = Date.now();
  let dt = currUpdate - lastUpdate;

  // Randomize the update time interval
  // to test the physics' stability
  if (dt > randomDT) {
     randomDT = 35 * Math.random() + 5;
     Player1.update(dt);
     Player2.update(dt);
     lastUpdate = currUpdate;
  }

  // CANVAS #1 (LEFT)
  ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
  background(ctx1);
  Player1.draw(ctx1);

  // CANVAS #2 (RIGHT)
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
  background(ctx2);
  Player2.draw(ctx2);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();


// EVENT LISTENERS -----------------------

window.addEventListener('keydown',
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Player.keys.hasOwnProperty(e.code))
      Player.keys[e.code] = true;
  }
)

window.addEventListener('keyup',
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (Player.keys.hasOwnProperty(e.code))
      Player.keys[e.code] = false;
  }
)


// Just a function to draw Background nothing to see here
function background(c) {
  const lineNumber = Math.floor(canvas1.height/10)

  c.fillStyle = 'gray'
  for(let i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++) {
    c.fillRect(0, lineNumber*i, canvas1.width, 1)
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<canvas width="100" height="160" id="canvas1"></canvas>
<span>Normal</span>
</div>

<div>
<canvas width="100" height="160" id="canvas2"></canvas>
<span>Locked</span>
</div>
```